Apple Mail: single zip attachment exceeds server limit for number of files
I'm trying to send an email with one attachment: a zip file. I'm getting an error back from the iCloud mail server that the number of files or folders in the attachment exceeds the limits.

The zip file is made of lot of files -- over 1,200 in one folder. So I'm guessing that the server is actually "reading" the contents of the zip file. (The total file size is around 2 Mb, so well within limits.)
I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.5. I'm using "Compress..." in the Finder to make the zip file.
This question from 8 years ago seems to be a similar issue: iCloud "message size violation" when sending zip containing more than 127 files
I'm wondering whether different forms of compression might produce a more monolithic attachment (but still be easily opened by normal people).

2GB via Mail? That won't work.

@X_841 Sorry, I meant Megabytes! ;-) Will change it.

You’ll have to make an encrypted dmg to contain the zip or perhaps put a password on the archive to prevent deeper inspection. Too bad you can’t share a cloud link instead of attaching…

@bmike Can Windows users open a dmg?

Unlikely without help of a third party tool. I would try password on the zip as that’s supported cross platform. It wasn’t clear what your problem or use case was for the receiving side.. @benwiggy so I wasn’t confident enough to answer

You can use a different archival method like cpio/tar/gzip/xar (and their combination) or just set a password.
